# access_control in Symfony3 doesn't work

Tags: php, security, routes, fosuserbundle, symfony

I use Symfony 3 and I have an issue when using `access_control` in the `app/config/security.yml`.

I installed FOSUserBundle and I discovered that the routes /login /resetting and /register are still available when the user has the role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`. I use the basic configuration as it is explained in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) but it doesn't works :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Is there any possibility that the error comes from another file ? I spent a week searching for an answer and I can't figure out where is the problem coming from. Also, I tried to reinstall Symfony on another project from scratch just to try with a fresh configuration and the same error occurs.

Thank you for your help !

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLDR6.jpg)

Comment: By default, the routes `/login`, `/resetting` and `/register` will be available even when logged in.

What error are you talking receiving?

Comment: I don't receive any error and I can log in successfully, but then I can still access those routes and the name of the user is displayed above the form with a link to logout. In other words, I can login all over again...

Comment: What is the problem exactly? It doesn't sound like there are any problems, since you say you can access those routes when set to anonymous, which is correct...

Comment: Maybe my English is a little confusing because I'm French. What I'm saying is that I shouldn't be able to access those routes when I'm loged in. I also attached a screenshot to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the routes `/login`, `/resetting` and `/register` will continue to be available even when logged in.

If you do not want this, you can do several things:

- [override the `FOSUserBundle:Security` controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html), and redirect somewhere when you are logged in.
- [override the templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html) and do not display the form when you are already logged in

Answer (score 1):

There are not any problems, it is quite normal that you accessed to these routes being authenticated or not :

> IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY: All users (even anonymous ones) have
>   this - this is useful when whitelisting URLs to guarantee access

This is the lowest level role.

But you can do this in your fonction that manages login if you want to be redirected to `/admin` when you want to access to `/login` being logged

```
if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('your_route_path_to_admin'));
}
```